# githubのリポジトリをcloneしようとすると「fatal: Could not read from remote repository.」のエラーが出る

Tags: github

初めまして。
teratailに質問を投稿しているのですが、回答がつきませんのでご協力をお願いしたいです。
[githubのリポジトリをcloneしようとすると「fatal: Could not read from remote repository.」のエラーが出る](https://teratail.com/questions/173543)

回答はこちらでも、teratailでも、どちらにしてくださっても問題ありません。

目的
・Laravelで開発したものをxserverで公開したい

現状
・xserverにssh接続した状態で、githubにあるリポジトリをcloneしようとしているがエラーが解決できない

お願いしたいこと
・cloneしようとしている時に出るエラーの解決方法を教えていただきたいです

試したこと
・$eval `ssh-agent`
・ssh -T git@github.com

簡単に説明するとこのような状態です。

他に何か必要な情報があれば、教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 試したことの2点は、ローカルPC上で実行しましたか？それともsshで接続した先で実行しましたか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。sshで接続した先で実行しました。

Answer (score -1):

sshでcloneすることばかり試していましたが、httpsでcloneすることができました。
ありがとうございました。